# fetching data from multiple tables -- single database

Tags: php, html

i am getting no error and no values for $con2 and $con3 when AND icutype = $icutype added in where clause.When removed i am getting total output correctly.

```
<?Php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","nimicudb");
$con2 = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","nimicudb");
$con3 = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","nimicudb");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    die();
}

if(!empty($_POST) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

    $icutype = $_POST["icutype"];
    $fromdate = $_POST['fromdate'];
    $todate = $_POST['todate'];

    $sql1= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(name) FROM `patients` WHERE date BETWEEN '$fromdate' AND '$todate' AND icutype = '$icutype'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1);
    $totalpatients=$row[0];

    $sql2= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT icubedstrength FROM `icustrength` WHERE icuname = '$icutype' ");
    $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2);
    $totalbeds=$row1[0];

    $sql3= mysqli_query($con2,"SELECT COUNT(icureturn48) FROM `patients1` WHERE date BETWEEN '$fromdate' AND '$todate' AND icutype = '$icutype' ");
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql3);
    $totalicureturn48=$row2[0];

    $sql4= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(datedischarge) FROM `patients` WHERE date BETWEEN '$fromdate' AND '$todate' AND icutype = '$icutype'");
    $row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql4);
    $totaldischarge=$row3[0];

    $sql5= mysqli_query($con3,"SELECT COUNT(reintbn48) FROM `patients2` WHERE date BETWEEN '$fromdate' AND '$todate' AND icutype = '$icutype'");
    $row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql5);
    $totalreintubation=$row4[0];

    $sql6= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(tubedate) FROM `patients` WHERE date BETWEEN '$fromdate' AND '$todate' AND icutype = '$icutype'");
    $row5 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql6);
    $totalintubation=$row5[0];

    $totaldays = (strtotime($todate) - strtotime($fromdate)) / (60 * 60 * 24);
    echo  "TOTAL DAYS - $totaldays </br>";
    echo "TOTAL PATIENTS - $totalpatients</br>";
    echo "TOTAL BEDS - $totalbeds</br>";
    echo "TOTAL discharge - $totaldischarge</br>";
    echo "TOTAL intubation - $totalintubation</br>";
    echo "TOTAL PATIENTS returned - $totalicureturn48</br>";
    echo "TOTAL reintubation - $totalreintubation</br>";

    $icureturnrate=(round(($totalicureturn48/$totaldischarge)*100));
    $reintubation_rate=(round(($totalreintubation/$totalintubation)*100));
    $urate=(round(($totalpatients/$totalbeds)*$totaldays));
    echo "utilization rate is  : $urate</br>";
    echo "% Return to ICU within 48 hours is  : $icureturnrate </br>";
    echo "% Re-intubation rate is  : $reintubation_rate";
}
?>



<html>


<form action='search.php' method='POST'>
<h5>SELECT ICU</h5>
<select name='icutype' >

    <option value="EICU">EICU</option>
    <option value="NMICU">NMICU</option>
    <option value="NSICU">NSICU</option>
    <option value="SBICU">SBICU</option>
</select>

</br>


    FROM DATE<input type="date" name="fromdate" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')); ?>"></br>


  TO DATE<input type="date" name="todate" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>"></br>


<input type='submit' name='calsubmit' value="CALCULATE"/>
</form>



</html>
```

This is my page  where i need advice.

THE OUTPUT OF THIS DISPLAYED LIKE BELOW

```
TOTAL DAYS - 30
TOTAL PATIENTS - 1
TOTAL BEDS - 6
TOTAL discharge - 1
TOTAL intubation - 1
**TOTAL PATIENTS returned - 0
**TOTAL reintubation - 0
utilization rate is : 5
% Return to ICU within 48 hours is : 0
% Re-intubation rate is : 0
```

THE `**` MARKED ITEMS ARE NOT GIVING ANY OUTPUT WHEN THE AND ADDED TO WHERE CLAUSE (`AND icutype = '$icutype'`)

Comment: Isn't the answer obvious? There aren't any rows with that ICU type in the date range.

Comment: Do you get a different result if you execute the same query outside PHP?

Comment: Why are you opening multiple connections to the same DB? You should be able to do everything with `$con`.

Comment: icutype is a foreign key present in all tables.$con2 and $con3 added because at first with $con the mentioned different tables patient 1 and patient 2 is not producing any result.Same table datas are fetched properly but this two table data not coming when i add AND icutype=$icutype.Prepared statements i wil try .i know the risks.

Comment: 1) You're wide open to SQLI, 2) You're establishing 3 different connections to the same DB, which is not necessary in any sense. With that said, have you tried to `echo` your `$_POST["icutype"]` variable or do `var_dump($icutype)` to make sure you're not dealing with empty variable(s)? Have you made sure you enter your `if()` condition?

Comment: echo giving correct result for icutype.

Comment: i can able to get result with single con but still marked items not giving result.Not even throwing any error, even i run the select line directly in database but it ran successfully with zero result.I am not understanding the issue.somebody plz help.

Answer (score 0):

Hai guys i sorted it out.
The problem is with some whitespace got saved along with the data in icutype column.I changed icutype =$icutype to icutype LIKE '%$icutype%' and it worked like helll.
Thanks guys.